# Output entire console output to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, console

I inherited a Windows batch file that is just over 6,000 lines long, and it is running as a scheduled task on Windows Server 2003 R2.

There are some echoes and redirects here and there in the batch code for writing to log files, but there are a couple of hundred calls and commands that are not logged.

So I want to capture the entire console output to a text file for evaluation and debugging.

I found a couple of solutions posted, but none I have tried actually work.

Is there a way to do this without having to add to the batch code itself in a couple of hundred places to try and get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper:

wrapper.cmd

```
call batch.cmd >>logfile.txt
```

you could also try to wrap you whole file body in

```
(
<body>
) >>logfile.txt
```

but that can be wonky depending on what's going on in the body, i found.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip.  It didn't give me any console output, only the same output as running my original.bat >> logfile.txt, and the parens didn't work.  But... using your wrapper did show me that there was a UAC permissions issue with one of the EXEs that the big batch file calls -- and that is a HUGE help.   So Thanks again!!!

Comment: Are you saying you get console output that doesn't get redirected by >>? If so, the executed programs don't use stdout. Maybe try adding 2>&1 to redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: redirected output does not redirect again. `(echo foobar>file.txt)>out.txt` will not write "foobar" to out.txt, but to file.txt. (for example I use `echo foobar>con` to write output to screen (only), even if the whole script is redirected to a file)